# Realm Object Server Installation Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: synchronization, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is it possible to run the [Realm Object Server](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/) on Ubuntu 14.04?
There doesn't seem to be explicit documentation on Realm's site that prevents this.

I ran the installation script using

```
# Setup Realm's PackageCloud repository
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/realm/realm/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# Update repositories
sudo apt-get update
```

The script works fine it detects my operating system and finishes without errors

```
Detected operating system as Ubuntu/trusty.
...
The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
```

However when I want to install the actual package

```
# Install the Realm Object Server
sudo apt-get install realm-object-server-de
```

I get the

```
E: Unable to locate package realm-object-server-de
```

Yes I did run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realm Object Server is not available for Ubuntu 14.04 at this time. We only packaged it for Ubuntu 16.04. We are working on providing more packages soon.

Comment: Any progress on that? :-)

Comment: Not at this time. How blocking is this for you?

Comment: My VPS admin said he have no time to add ubuntu 16.04 iso :-D

Comment: I hope to have soon 16.04 so I will check your great work. Im planning to use it in mobile social app.

Comment: You don't have access to CentOS 6 or 7 on your VPS, either? What about using our AWS AMIs?